# Customize a new menu in an existing tab in word

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

How can I create a new menu in an existing tab like the outlook button? (see picture). I tried it with the Ribbon XML add-in and could only customise a new tab in the "**Maillings-ribbon**".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" loadImage="LoadImage" >
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabMailings" >
        <group idMso="GroupMailMergeStart">
          <menu idMso="MailMergeSelectRecipients">
            <button id="button1"
               imageMso="HappyFace" 
               getDescription="GetDescription"
               label="My Button"
               onAction="OnAction" />
          </menu>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I found a list with the Control IDs for Office (see picture). I tried it many times with the XML. See the following code:

It would be great if you could help me...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to create a new menu in an existing tab. you can create a new tab with menu.